# Count of unique words in multiple text files in a folder using awk in windows

Tags: awk

I have multiple files in a folder (d:\text).

Using gawk (in windows), I want to generate a list of words and their occurence count in the format below:

```
a 12145
the 22483
but 754
```

etc.

Comment: Cool - what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Considering inputs:

```
$ ls ./in*
./in1.txt  ./in2.txt
$ cat in*
What's up Buddy. How are you doin Buddy?
What's up Man. I am happy and good and awesome.
```

AWK counting words with associative array, words treated as alpha characters (You will need to tune up and also create logic for upper/lower cases etc.). Note there is also added count 4 for empty string:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { RS="[^A-Za-z]"; } { words[$0]++; } END { for ( i in words ) print(i " " words[i]); }' ./in*
happy 1
are 1
 4
What 2
awesome 1
How 1
Buddy 2
and 2
I 1
up 2
good 1
doin 1
am 1
Man 1
you 1
s 2
```